# Filling a path with a gradient on iOS

Tags: ios, uibezierpath, cagradientlayer

On a `CAShapeLayer`, I've drawn a closed `UIBezierPath`. I can fill this shape by setting the `fillColor`, however I want to fill the shape with a gradient. How can I set up the `CAGradientLayer`so it clips to the shape outlined by the bezier path?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is a mask.  CAGradientlayer has a -setMask method that can clip it to the bounds of your shape like so:

`[gradientLayer setMask:shapeLayer];`

Answer (score 20):

A draft example would be the following:

```
...
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

UIColor *gradientColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.51 green:0.0 blue:0.49 alpha:1.0];

NSArray *gradientColors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
                          (id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor, 
                          (id)gradientColor.CGColor, 
                          (id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor, nil];
CGFloat gradientLocations[] = {0, 0.5, 1};
CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (CFArrayRef)gradientColors, gradientLocations);

UIBezierPath *roundedRectanglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200) cornerRadius:6];
CGContextSaveGState(context);
[roundedRectanglePath fill];
[roundedRectanglePath addClip];
CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, CGPointMake(10, 10), CGPointMake(210, 10), 0);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
CGGradientRelease(gradient);

...
```

Comment: This is nice, but you should also release the gradient and color space.

Comment: since the original post featured a Mask, I also added the following:

`CGContextAddPath(context, roundedRectanglePath.CGPath);`
`CGContextClip(context);` 

before `CGContextDrawLinearGradient`